multiple crashes related to "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]"
Starting last few days, out of the blue, we get multiple crash reports from google analytics related to "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]". First crash seen at 04-11-2024.
No code change was made in last 2 months.
Currently this is seen on earlier Android OS devices (8.1, 8.1.0, 9, 10).
compileSdk 34. targetSdkVersion 34. minSdkVersion 23.
There are several crashes that come from different places in code, most of them related to third party SDKs (such as google analytics and more).
They all ended with the next logs:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]
   at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java)
   at android.util.ArrayMap.put(ArrayMap.java)

One full logcat example:
          Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]
   at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:174)
   at android.util.ArrayMap.put(ArrayMap.java:463)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.putString(BaseBundle.java:503)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.l.n(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.scionintegration.l.i(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.gmsg.ap.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.r.x(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.r.e(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.an.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at m.bcf.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24)
   at m.bcf.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@24
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve it?
Thanks.

When you say there were no code-changes, does that also include libraries? Or did you update one of them? And did any of the APIs you access change?

No change in my code for third party libraries. In the build.gradle I see that some APIs have updated versions, but I did not update any.

To me it looks like, the Strings you are trying to cast were originally Character[]. But if you did not change anything, this can only occur through external APIs or libraries that send data to your code or return data. Can you check how the same places in code handle this problem on newer android versions?

This is difficult to check, since the traces actually not involved with my code, also cannot identify the API that cause it.

One of my friends has the same issue, and resolved it by avoiding the use of the AdMob SDK on Android versions earlier than 11.
